# Issue with assembly language... and How do you do a new line?

Tags: linux, assembly

I'm starting to learn assembly language. The program I need to do is very simple.
1 - Read a 4-digit number (can be a negative number)
2 - Output the number the entered number
3 - Calculate/Output the half of the entered number
4 - Calculate/Output the double of the entered number

So... this is the code... first, the data section

```
section .data ; Data segment
    msgPrompt       db 'Please enter a number ' ; Ask the user to enter a number
    lenMsgPrompt    equ $-msgPrompt          ; The length of the message
    msgNumber       db 'The entered number is '
    lenMsgNumber    equ $-msgNumber                 
    msgHalf         db 'The half of the entered number is '
    lenMsgHalf      equ $-msgHalf
    msgDouble       db 'The double of the entered numbered is '
    lenMsgDouble    equ $-msgDouble
```

Then the uninitialized data (for the user input)

```
section .bss        ; Uninitialized data
    userNumber    resb 5
    halfNumber    resb 5
    doubleNumber  resb 5
```

Then... the code segment...

```
    section .text       ; Code Segment

       global _start
       _start:

       ;Prompt the user
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, msgPrompt
       mov edx, lenMsgPrompt
       int 80h

       ; Read and store the user input
       mov eax, 3
       mov ebx, 2
       mov ecx, userNumber  
       mov edx, 5       ; 5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
       int 80h

       ; Output the message 'The entered number is '
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, msgNumber
       mov edx, lenMsgNumber
       int 80h  

       ; Output the number entered
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, userNumber
       mov edx, 5
       int 80h  

       ; Output the message 'The half of the entered number is '
       mov eax, 4   
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, msgHalf
       mov edx, lenMsgHalf
       int 80h

       ; Calculate the half of the number entered
       mov eax, [userNumber]
       shr eax, 1       ; Shift to the right by one bit
       mov [halfNumber], eax

       ; Output half of the number entered
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, halfNumber
       mov edx, 5
       int 80h

       ; Output the message 'The double of the entered numbered is '
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, msgDouble
       mov edx, lenMsgDouble
       int 80h

       ; Calculate the double of the number entered
       mov ebx, [userNumber]
       shl ebx, 1       ; Shift the the left by one bit
       mov [doubleNumber], ebx

       ; Output double of the number entered
       mov eax, 4
       mov ebx, 1
       mov ecx, doubleNumber
       mov edx, 5
       int 80h

       ; Leave program
       mov eax, 1
       mov ebx, 0
       int 0x80
```

This is the final result... [Here](http://i239.photobucket.com/albums/ff19/oldboys11/AssemblyII.jpg) (I don't have enough reputation yet to post images...)

As you can see, there is problem... Also, I would like to have a new line after 'The half of the number is xxxxx'.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're doing arithmetic on ASCII codes for the digits, instead of the numeric value.

Comment: Ya, this is the problem... how can I 'convert' the ascii value to integer value?

Comment: @Triwis: Subtract the ASCII code for zero, which is `0x30` or 48.  But you still have individual digits of a decimal number, so if you use arithmetic instructions you still need to worry about carries and borrowing.  Or you can convert to a binary (computer-friendly) number, do the arithmetic, and convert back.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing EOL codes (13, 10)?

```
msgHalf         db 'The half of the entered number is ', 13, 10
```